# GETDATE - number of dates - a column / division in SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I need to do a calculation like this:

```
(Get today's date - 219 - HISTSTARTDATE)  / 7 AS 'Weeks Of History'
```

When I do it like this

```
(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - DATEADD(DAY, -219, GETDATE()) - HISTSTART) / 7 AS 'Weeks Of History'
```

I get an error

> The data types datetime and date are incompatible in the subtract operator

I am pretty confused because I believe it was working for me before. Does someone may have an idea what can be wrong and how to fix it?

Please let me know if you know.

Comment: Result of DateDiff is an integer, call that NumDaysSinceDayZero,
The Result of DateAdd is a DATETIME (because of getdate()), call the Date219DaysAgo,
What type is HISTSTART?

Are you sure you want to do:
(NumDaysSinceDayZero - Date219DaysAgo - HISTSTART)? You should cast(getdate() as DATE); and maybe HISTSTART, as well

Comment: HISTSTART can you please tell me the data type of this column

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working in SQL we can't subtract to date like below

> **Wrong**:
> '2020-02-09' - '2020-01-02'
> **Right** : DateDiff(day/hour/year, '2020-02-09' ,'2020-01-02')

So your answer has to be like this :

> **DateDiff**(Day, (Get today's date) , **DateDiff**(day, dateadd(), HISTSTARTDATE) )/ 7 AS 'Weeks Of History'

Code:

```
Select DATEDIFF(DAY,DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()) ,cast(DATEADD(DAY, -219, GETDATE()) - HISTSTART as date)) / 7  AS 'Weeks Of History'
```